# What's the maximum length of oauth tokens from the Twitter API?

Tags: api, twitter, oauth

I need to store oauth_token and oauth_token_secret of each user granting access to my web app and I was wondering if these tokens would have a max length so I could use `varchar(n)`. I'm aware Facebook's is 255.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this Quora thread: http://www.quora.com/OAuth-1/Whats-the-maximum-length-of-an-OAuth-access-token-key-secret-pair

Summary: There's apparently no official limit on the length of a Oauth token/secret, but it seems Twitter is using an internal limit of 50 chars.

My recommendation: Don't limit the size. Use "varchar" (without a number).